# specified cast is not found

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

I'm trying to return a list consisting of some elements (sql query) but the debugger stops at the director.oscars line.

I declared oscars as a private int and the data from the database is all correct.

If I omit that one line there is no error anymore and a list is returned with the whole oscars column full of 0's.

```
  public static List<Director> AllDirectors()
    {
        string command;
        command = "SELECT directorId, firstName, lastName, birthdate, gender, oscars " +
            " FROM directors order by directorId";
        OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(command, connectionString);
        DataTable datatable = new DataTable();
        adapter.Fill(datatable);


        List<Director> list = new List<Director>();
        for (int i = 0; i < datatable.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            Director director= new Director();
            director.directorId = datatable.Rows[i].Field<int>("directorId");
            director.firstName = datatable.Rows[i].Field<string>("firstName");
            director.lastName= datatable.Rows[i].Field<string>("lastName");
            director.oscars = datatable.Rows[i].Field<int>("oscars");
            director.birthdate = datatable.Rows[i].Field<DateTime>("birthdate");
            director.gender = datatable.Rows[i].Field<string>("gender");




            list.Add(Director);
        }
        return list;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most likely reason for the invalid cast exception is that the `oscars` field in the database is *not* an `int`.

Check the exact type of the field, and replace `int` in `datatable.Rows[i].Field<int>("oscars")` with the correct type. For example, if the field is nullable integer, you would need to use `datatable.Rows[i].Field<int?>("oscars");` (with a question mark).

Note: if `Director.oscars` is non-nullable, but the database field is, use `??` to replace nulls with zeros, like this:

```
director.oscars = datatable.Rows[i].Field<int?>("oscars") ?? 0;
```

Comment: replacing int by int? did the job, thanks a lot. I'm still need to learn a lot in C#